# I have tested my code on pyCharm and it works, but on Leetcode it gives me a KeyError and doesn't work. How do I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
romanD = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
oper = []
s = input('roman')


class Solution(object):
    def romanToInt(self, s):
        rtype = int
        for j in range(len(s)):
            if j+1 == len(s):
                break
            elif romanD[s[j]] < romanD[s[j+1]]:
                oper.append(-1 * romanD[s[j]])
            elif romanD[s[j]] >= romanD[s[j+1]]:
                oper.append(romanD[s[j]])
        oper.append(romanD[s[len(s) - 1]])
        return sum(oper)


b = Solution()
print(b.romanToInt(s))
```

The error:

```
KeyError: '"'
    elif romanD[s[j]] < romanD[s[j+1]]:
Line 12 in romanToInt (Solution.py)
    print(b.romanToInt(s))
Line 21 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

I specifically wrote the 'if then break' part to not go out of the range of input but to no vain.

Comment: Apparently leetcode passes a string which contains quotes and your code can't handle that.

Comment: You can address this issue with the line `if s == "": return 0` at the top of your function

Comment: what is up with rtype = int? is that redundant or...?

Comment: I tried what Ben Grossmann suggested, but it didn't work, even on pyCharm. Maybe I did it wrong, I put the if statement right under the function opening.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the word you entered is not in the romanD list and there will be uppercase and lowercase matching, I made a few changes in the code, you can use it.

```
romanD = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
oper = []
s = input('roman').upper().split('"')
s=s[0]

class Solution(object):
    def romanToInt(self, s):
        for j in range(len(s)):
            if j+1 == len(s):
                break
            elif romanD[s[j]] < romanD[s[j+1]]:
                oper.append(-1 * romanD[s[j]])
            elif romanD[s[j]] >= romanD[s[j+1]]:
                oper.append(romanD[s[j]])
        try:
            oper.append(romanD[s[len(s) - 1]])
        except:
            print('the word you entered is incorrect',s)
        return sum(oper)


b = Solution()
print(b.romanToInt(s))
```

Comment: There seems to be a mistake, it calls the except statement when i input a single quote but when I type in ' "v" ' it gives a KeyError on pyCharm.

Comment: Yeah ... I think this a mistake of Leetcode. It says your output is 58 when it should be 3. Same thing with me, says output is 61 when it's 3. That's why I have been double-checking with pyCharm. Thank you, your answer is most probably right.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding

```
s = s.replace('"','')
```

! Thanks for the ideas